# Using DataGenerator with TensorFlow, buffer_size error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a Unet model written in TensorFlow that I would like to train on a dataset of cloud images. To do so I created a DataGenerator like this

```
class CloudDataGen(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(
            self,
            list_ids,
            batch_size,
            input_size=(512, 512),
            num_channels=3,
            shuffle=True,
            mode=None):

        self.list_ids = list_ids
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.num_channels = num_channels
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.mode = mode
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_ids))
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.floor(len(self.list_ids) / self.batch_size))


    def __data_generation(self, ids):

        x = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.input_size, self.num_channels))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.input_size), dtype=int)

        # Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(ids):
           
            if self.mode == 'train':
                image_dir = TRAIN_SOURCES + TRAIN_SOURCE_NAME + ID + '/image.npy'
            else:
                image_dir = TEST_SOURCES + TEST_SOURCE_NAME + ID + '/image.npy'

            x[i, ] = np.load(image_dir)
            # Store class
            if self.mode == 'train':
                y[i] = np.asarray(Image.open(TRAIN_LABELS + TRAIN_LABEL_NAME + ID + '/labels.tif'))
            else:
                y[i] = np.asarray(Image.open(TEST_LABELS + TEST_LABEL_NAME + ID + '/labels.tif'))

        return x, y

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        indexes = self.indexes[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]

        list_ids_current_batch = [self.list_ids[k] for k in indexes]

        # Generate data
        x, y = self.__data_generation(list_ids_current_batch)

        return x, y
```

Then to compile and train I use the following code

```
traingen, validationgen = get_data_gens()

unet_model = build_unet_model()
unet_model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                   loss='mse',
                   metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU(num_classes=2)]
                   )

NUM_EPOCHS = 2


model_history = unet_model.fit(traingen,
                               validation_data=validationgen,
                               epochs=NUM_EPOCHS
                               )
```

Unfortunately if I try to run the code I get this error
`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: buffer_size must be greater than zero. [Op:ShuffleDatasetV2]` for which I can't find a solution.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: This error occurs when you are directly giving the path of the directory first store the path of images into a list and then pass the list of the paths to it...

Comment: Follow this link for further details, your work is the same as it... At least for Data Generation

https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/